# I can't run my flutter app on my device Huawei P10 Lite

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, sdk

I am new in Flutter. I create small app for testing and run app on Genymotion simulator and it's running very well, and In real device with Android 4.4.4 and newer running very well, BUT i can't run app on my Android 4.4.2 device(Huawei P10). Help me if you know, How can I run app on my Android  4.4.2 device?
This is `flutter doctor` command output:

```
PS D:\Mobile\AndroidStudioProjects\MyCardApp> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (4 days ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • HUAWEI P7 L10 (mobile) • 7N2NEF149K045449 • android-arm • Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

• No issues found!
```

Output When I run `flutter run`

```
PS D:\Mobile\AndroidStudioProjects\MyCardApp> flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in MyCardApp...                           0,7s
Launching lib\main.dart on HUAWEI P7 L10 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       105,5s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                     
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)
```

Comment: Can you give us details about how you "cannot" run it? What is the problem? Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Sorry for my English, in my Huawei device  this is not give me any errors, but on Samsung (Android 4.4.4) and newer  its running  . I paste run  process on my question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, activate developer seetings in your device, make sure to connect your device to the computer by a USB, in the developer settings enable "USB Debugging", then you should be able to run the app on your device.
**If that doesn't work** do this:

1. Go to Developer options
2. Under Networking, tap on Select USB Configuration
3. Select MIDI device

Comment: My USB debugging is enabled. Developer options are opened. But in my device(HUAWEI P7 Lite10) I don't have `USB configuration` option